# django models not accept the email?

Tags: python, django

trying to setting up a small website,a newbie in django . when i create a newsletter setup in django, but the email not saving the admin panel. here is my codes. take a look .

models.py

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

views.py

```
def Newsletter(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    email = email(email=email)
    email.save()
    message.success(request, "email Successfully added")

return render(request, 'index.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('newsletter', views.Newsletter, name="newsletter"),
```

template

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="subscribe-form subscribe-form-dec subscribe-mrg">
                        <form id="Newsletter" class="validate subscribe-form-style" novalidate=""  name="Newsletter" method="post" action="/Newsletter">
                            
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll" class="mc-form">
                                <input class="email" type="email" required="" placeholder="Your email address…" name="Newsletter" value="" id="Newsletter">
                                <div class="mc-news" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <input type="text" value="" tabindex="-1" name="Subscribers">
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Nothing getting. just loading.

Comment: That might mean your DB is locked. If you are using SQLite make sure you don't have it opened in any other program. Restart your computer to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py:

Here maybe you are overriding the name of the view with the name of Model, try this:

```
from .models import Newsletter


def adding_email_to_newsletter(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        Newsletter.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        message.success(request, "email Successfully added")

return render(request, 'index.html')
```

the urls.py

```
path("adding_email_to_newsletter", views.adding_email_to_newsletter, name="adding_email_to_newsletter"),
```

template:

Here you miss the csrf_token that is required for post submits by default [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf) and the using of the tag `url` for best practices.

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="subscribe-form subscribe-form-dec subscribe-mrg">
    <form id="Newsletter" class="validate subscribe-form-style" novalidate=""  name="Newsletter" method="post" action="{% url 'adding_email_to_newsletter' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll" class="mc-form">
            <input class="email" type="email" required="" placeholder="Your email address…" name="Newsletter" value="" id="Newsletter">
            <div class="mc-news" aria-hidden="true">
                <input type="text" value="" tabindex="-1" name="Subscribers">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This will perform exactly the same as the code in the question except not crashing if the email already exists, which is not the problem OP was asking about.

Comment: you named the view as same as your Model and is overriding

Comment: In that case it might be useful to put that front and center of your answer, it's not immediately obvious

Comment: i did this because i saw many things to improve the code. override was only one thing, he miss the csrf_token, he didn't use the Model to create the instance, he didn't use the urls in template, etc.

Comment: That is great, but I think op would be helped more if he understood what caused his original problem It would help him even more if you explained your other changes but that would be outside the scope of the question. "Replace your code with this" does not help him become a better programmer. Just mentioning that the recursion is causing the hang will probably help him a lot.

Comment: i agree with that, but the code isn't too long, and there are just 2 o 3 changes. But i will mention this in each file.

Comment: got a template error adding the same code. Invalid block tag on line 203: 'urls', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: @zach sorry is `{% url '' %}` without the `s` at the end. i've just update my response.

Comment: @Diego Puente  AttributeError at /adding_email_to_newsletter
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Check in the views.py that Newsletter has to be the model imported from models.py, or update the answer with an update of the views.py at the bottom.

Comment: def adding_email_to_newsletter(request):  # match this view name in the urls.py
    if request.method=="POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        adding_email_to_newsletter.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        message.success(request, "email Successfully added")
        
    return render(request, 'index.html')

Comment: class adding_email_to_newsletter(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = models.Manager()  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

Comment: models.py didn't have to change, i've just update my response adding models.py. and in the views.py change this `adding_email_to_newsletter.objects.get_or_create(email=email)` for this: `Newsletter.objects.get_or_create(email=email)`

Comment: cannot import name 'adding_email_to_newsletter' from '*****.models

Comment: the only place that you have to import the view function `adding_email_to_newsletter` is in your urls.py

Comment: @Diego Puente  Nothing happened bro, i tried my best,any way thanks for give some your precious time to spend for this.